# How to add dictionary items when I loop in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to parse information from eml files in python. I set up my `extract` function to parse what I want to get. The problem is I have 10,000+ files and I don't know how to add every extracted information to one object.

When I run the `extract` function on one eml file, the output looks like

```
{'from': 'Joe', 'to': 'Robert', 'text': 'Hey Robert'}
```

The output is a `dict` object. Now I want to append my extracted ouput to my existing output (`name`) to collect every information from 10,000 files in `name`. How can I do this? I used following code, but the `name` object only has the information from last file in `FList` (which is a list of each 10,000+ files).

```
for i in range(len(FList)):
  f = open(FList[i])
  name=extract(f, f.name)
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to map the filename to the dictionary with the data from the file.  To do that, you'd do something like:

```
file_map = {}
for fname in FList:
    with open(fname) as f:
        file_map[fname] = extract(f, fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `name` object is being overwritten in your loop. Since name is meant to be a dict, and dicts are passed by reference (google on pass by reference to get more info), you can do something like this:

```
names = dict()
for my_file in file_lst:
    with open(my_file) as f:
        extract(f,names)

def extract(f, names):
    #modify your names dict here such as:
    names["something new"] = "a new value"
```

After you are done with looping over `file_lst` you will have names populated with all the info from all files, as it will be retained across the loop...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you want to store your data. If you just want a list of entries, then you just need to append the extracted data to a list as follows:

```
name = []

for file_name in FList:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        name.append(extract(f, f.name))
```

In `extract()`, you could add another dictionary entry to hold the filename of the entry before returning it.